# How to configure Pidgin without Tor?

Tags: configuration, chat

I want to connect to an IRC server but the server is rejecting Tor users. 
How can I use Pidgin, or any other IRC program to connect outside Tor?

I tried **Pidgin >>  Modify >> Proxy >> Proxy type: No proxy** but Pidgin gives an error:

> Unable to connect: Connection refused

When I use **>> Global proxy settings** and try to connect then Pidgin gives the error:

> ERROR :Tor exit node detected (port 80)

Comment: What OS are you using? Tails?